# Command Line equivalent to pressing Remove button on Virtual Directory's Application Name setting

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, command-line-interface

The title pretty much says it.  I need a command line equivalent to pressing the Remove button on the Application Name setting when looking at the properties of a Virtual Directory in IIS6 on a Windows Server 2003.  I need this for a batch file.  If there is an alternative for a VBScript that would work also.

I know with

```
Cscript.exe adsutil.vbs SET Path Value
```

I can alter settings but cannot find a list of what settings I can alter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the remove button actually removes the application from the virtual directory, the equivalent in adsutil is to use the command:

```
APPDELETE Path
```

See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781546%28WS.10%29.aspx) for a full list of commands to use with adsutil.